# Sensor To Sensor Variability - Generalizing One Sensor Calibration To Many

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, anova, confidence-interval, linear

I have 7 different sensors of the same type that try to qualitatively estimate soil water content (SWC) based off of the capacitance of the soil/medium they're touching. However, I have read a few articles that use regression to map the voltage output of the sensor to the volumetric water content of the medium (VWC).

This mapping can be considered a medium-specific calibration. That is, ideally speaking, you should be able to use the data obtained from a single sensor to calibrate all sensors to that specific soil. This is what I would like to do, so I only have to calibrate a single sensor for the soil, and I can then use the fitted parameters for the rest of my sensors.

Specifically, I read an [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/342751186_Capacitive_Soil_Moisture_Sensor_Theory_Calibration_and_Testing) that used linear regression to map this relationship between voltage output and volumetric water content. However, it was only for a single sensor and a single medium.

I tried running the experiment with multiple sensors and a different medium (sandy loam) from the article. I created a series of pots of the soil with different VWC. I then one by one put each sensor along with a temperature probe into the soil with a specific technique to ensure consistency and then I took the average of 3800 samples in that specific position. This I repeated a minimum of 4 times for each sensor in each soil/water mixture.

When I look at the linear regression for each sensor individually, there appears to be a very nice pattern of linearity and a very high R^2 coefficient. [image: Example of individual sensors] I get an even higher R^2 value, when I also include the temperature into the regression model, but for now I've decided to focus on the voltage alone.

I tried calculating the 95% C.I intervals of the linear regression models and plotting them, hoping to see some sort of overlap. But none were found [image]. They do however intercept in the middle, and most of them seem to group up "fairly close" to one another. I used the [following code](https://pastecode.io/s/n21hfc1d) to compute it for each regression model. (Please note, that the confidence interval are so small, that they appear as lines.)

I also ran a one-way ANOVA analysis using the sensor as treatment and the voltage reading as the outcome. I got a p-value north of 0.9, indicating that there was no difference between the sensors.

However, using a two-way ANOVA analysis with pot and sensor being the treatments I got the following result:

[image: Two-way ANOVA].

Indicating that there is a difference between which sensor used the voltage output.

The situation is that, I do not need to be ultra precise; a precision of +/- 5-8% is acceptable. So, if there is any method where I can trade precision for accuracy, I could use that.

That is, I can see that the confidence intervals all fall within more or less the same region; Is there any way I can mark this super-region as sort of the "general" 95% confidence interval or some method akin to that?

On the other hand, I realize I have a small sample size (approx. 151 total.) I could increase this by taking more samples, but it is very laborious and time consuming to do. And I would rather spend time working on integrating the sensor into the system.

Problem is, I am having a hard time quantifying the non-generalizability of the sensors. Are there any measurements that can quantify this, so I can make a more informed decision on whether to try and gather more samples or just work towards integrating it?

Finally, how am I to interpret the two different ANOVA results? I currently interpret it as; Different sensors will react differently at different VWC levels. However in general in any given VWC, the sensors will act the same?